# How to identify the TimePickerDialog called inside the OnTimeSetListener method?

Tags: android, time, listener, picker, timepicker

I have two different TimePickerDialogs that share the same callback method, and I'm trying to figure out how to differentiate between them. Currently the only way they differ is in their title, although that can change.

Anyways, how do I get the TimePickerDialog's title, given only the TimePicker that's passed into the TimePickerDialog.OnTimeSetListener method?

Thanks a lot.

Answer (score 0):

Just store the currently used TimePickerDialog in some class variable before you open the dialog. When your callback is called refer to that variable to distinguish between those two objects